# how to hyperlink an image in R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

Based upon my understanding of markdown syntax, this is how you add a hyperlink to an embedded image, yet this does not seem to work using R Markdown. What am I doing wrong?

[![alt text][local path to saved image]][web link]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this way: `![Alt text](Web link or path)`
Examples: `![Image name](img/image.png)`  or
          `![Image name](http://www.host.com/image.png)`

Combining with the normal syntax for a hyperlink `[text](URL)`, we have:

```
[![Alt text](Web link or path)](web link to website)
```

Example:

```
[![Image name](image.png)](http://www.host.com/link.html)
```

Comment: I need to link from an embedded image to a website. Not simply embed an image and not simply link to an image online. Thanks.

Comment: [![Alt text](Web link or path)](web link to website)

Comment: the alt text doesn't show up

Comment: This works, but it would be great to open the link in a new tab or window as opposed to on the same page.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me knitted to HTML.  The code references an image from a local data store "./data/appStore.png"  The image links to the app store url "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-toy-box/id1217665205?mt=8".  When hovering over the image the user sees, "My Toy Box on App Store".  The alt text "MyToyBox" doesn't appear.

```
[![MyToyBox](./data/appStore.png "My Toy Box on App Store")](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-toy-box/id1217665205?mt=8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking the same and `<a href = "https://the link"> ![](images/logo.png)` works as well.