# script to add links to all images in markdown file

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I have a workflow where I'm downloading Google Docs as docx, then processing them to markdown for export to other formats in the R environment.

When I convert to markdown with pandoc_convert, I get embedded images, but they're not linked.
I want to add link syntax similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235301/how-to-hyperlink-an-image-in-r-markdown),

i.e. I want this (not linked): 
    `![m'lady](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAUP1.jpg)`

[image: m'lady]

to be (linked):
`[![m'lady](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAUP1.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAUP1.jpg)`
[image: m'lady]

for every image in a document. How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much toil, I put this function together, which solves my issue:

```
 addLinksToPhotos<-function(mdfile){
  d<-readLines(mdfile)
  s<-sapply(d,function(x) {
    replacementPattern="[\\1(\\2)](\\2)\\3"
    gsub('.*?(?<firstpart>!\\[[^\\]]*?\\])\\((?<filename>.*)\\)(?<potentialHTML>\\{.*?\\})?.*?',x=x,replacement=replacementPattern,perl=T)
  },USE.NAMES = F)
  writeLines(s,mdfile)
    }    

    #usage
    addLinksToPhotos("myRMarkdownDoc.rmd")
```

It will read every line in the markdown file, looking for the photo `![]()` pattern, including where it has style coding in braces `![](){}`. It will modify each instance to have a linked image `[![]()](){}`.